# How to use Python to do web crawling on a website that requires Google account to sign in?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am new to Python and I would like to use Python to crawls several websites that requires Google account sign in.
For example, i want to crawl a website xxx.appspot.com and i need to login my Google account to access it since this database needs verification and i am authorized personnel.

when i do things like:

```
content=urllib.urlopen(target_url).read()
```

The "content" i get is, of course, just a login page. How do i implement the code such that the crawler can sign in the Google account before i do the actual crawling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) and [cookielib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html).

Below code works fine for me for gmail login. Try this with your respective url and stuff.

```
import mechanize        

def gmaillogin():
    browser = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    r = browser.open("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=http://mail.google.com/mail/&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1") 
    browser.select_form(nr=0)               
    browser.form["Email"] = "emailid"
    browser.form["Passwd"] = "password"    
    browser.submit()                        

    html = browser.response().readlines()    
    
    print(html)  

                      
     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gmaillogin()
```

Comment: Thanks you. Your code is really a good example and based on your code, i successfully wrote the code i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
import imaplib

class pygmail:
  def __init__(self):
    self.IMAP_SERVER='imap.gmail.com'
    self.IMAP_PORT=993
    self.M = None
    self.response = None

  def login(self, username, password):
    self.M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self.IMAP_SERVER, self.IMAP_PORT)
    rc, self.response = self.M.login(username, password)#Provide your user name and password
    return rc

  def logout(self):
    self.M.logout()

g = pygmail()
g.login('username@gmail.com', 'pa$$word')
print g.response
```

this will help you getting the basic data out of the mail, there are many methods available via which you can use to get the data out of the mails like read mail, unread mail, spams and many other methods. you can found few more methods at http://segfault.in/2010/12/sending-gmail-from-python/, Please feel free to revert back.